# page scrolling technique/transition- how to

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll

I'm not at all sure what it's called, but I'm seeing this technique used more and more. What is it? How does one do it?

Ex:
http://fearthegrizzly.com/  -  scroll down, image fades as "We Love Film" is brought up
http://www.minervastreetwear.com/lookbook/  -  scrolling rates of image of guy in hat vs guy in jacket vs text

Comment: that fearthegrizzly.com only adjusts css opacity when the page is scrolled down or up, you can have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/RP9sB/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called parallax. Maybe you want to read this blog article:

http://smashinghub.com/7-jquery-parallax-and-scrolling-effect-plugins.htm